# flutter: build fails after adding firebase_admob

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-admob

I'm trying to add `firebase_admob` to my firebase app and getting the error below.

> Could not determine the dependencies of task
>   ':firebase_core:compileDebugAidl'.
>
> > The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base is being requested by various other libraries at [[17.0.0,17.0.0]], but
> >     resolves to 16.5.0. Disable the plugin and check your dependencies
> >     tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies.

I tried adding `com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck = true` to the gradle build file. Then this error goes away but the flutter app crashes when trying to launch in emulator.

below are my dependencies

```
  random_string: 0.0.2
  firebase_auth: ^0.14.0+5
  firebase_database: ^3.0.7
  google_sign_in: ^4.0.7
  flutter_facebook_login: 2.0.1
  provider: 3.0.0
  rxdart: ^0.22.2
  flutter_svg: ^0.14.0
  collection: ^1.14.11
  audioplayers: ^0.13.2
  firebase_admob: ^0.9.0+7
```

Flutter version

```
Flutter 1.9.1+hotfix.2 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 2d2a1ffec9 (6 days ago) • 2019-09-06 18:39:49 -0700
Engine • revision b863200c37
Tools • Dart 2.5.0
```

Appreciate any help to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that two different plugins are referencing two different versions of the underlying Firebase gradle artifacts for Android.

The error message is giving you good advice about how to check the exact problem:

```
./gradlew :app:dependencies
```

Try running that command from the `android` subfolder of your Flutter project and see what it says.

Comment: I ran a `flutter clean` and tried again. Then the issue got reduced to this: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/28647. Downgrading to `firebase_admob 0.5.5` seems to be the fix for the moment. 

Thanks for ur answer.